# How to calculate a value basing on several variables?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, calculation

I have a dataset (df) like this:

```
Iso conc.   rep time    OD
1   1      1    0     0.2
1   1.5    2    0     0.2
1   2      3    0     0.2
2   1      1    0     0.3
2   1.5    2    0     0.25
2   2      3    0     0.3
1   1      1    1     0.4
1   1.5    2    1     0.35
1   2      3    1     0.38
2   1      1    1     0.4
2   1.5    2    1     0.45
2   2      3    1     0.43
```

And I want to get the result `growth=OD(time=1)-OD(time=0)` basing on Iso, conc, and rep.

The output would be like this:

```
Iso conc.   rep time    growth
1   1      1    1      0.2
1   1.5    2    1      0.15
1   2      3    1      0.18
2   1      1    1      0.1
2   1.5    2    1      0.2
2   2      3    1      0.13
```

I have been thinking to use data.table to calculate the growth.

```
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, , by = .(Iso,conc.,rep,set)]
```

But I don't know how to write the part before two comma. Could somebody help me?

Comment: i see no `time=2`

Comment: oops, sorry. wrong typing. correct it now. 'growth=OD(time=1)-OD(time=0)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` you can simply do:

```
dt[,.(growth = OD[time==1]-OD[time==0]),.(Iso,conc.,rep)]
#   Iso conc. rep growth
#1:   1   1.0   1   0.20
#2:   1   1.5   2   0.15
#3:   1   2.0   3   0.18
#4:   2   1.0   1   0.10
#5:   2   1.5   2   0.20
#6:   2   2.0   3   0.13
```

Comment: I was so close! Thanks a lot! Haha ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with:

```
DT [, list(growth = OD[time == 1] - OD[time == 0]), by=.(Iso,conc.,rep)]
```

Or alternatively, if you are sure there are only two values in each group:

```
DT [order(time), list(growth = diff(OD), by=.(Iso,conc.,rep)]
```

Comment: So you mean if I have more time points (e.g. 0, 1, 2,3...), then i can't use diff anymore, right?

Comment: To guarantee order, could use `DT[order(time), ...]` for the second one.

Comment: @Frank should I order(OD) or order(time)?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo at first, I meant `order(time)`. If you have more times, `diff` will just take differences between adjacent values (for 1 minus 0, for 2 - 1, and so on) @Ziming

Comment: @Ziming `order(time)` is right, see edit. And yes that's right about having more time points, not if you only want 0 and 1 difference. (You could always filter with a `[time <= 1]` step beforehand.

Comment: Ok! I get it now! Thanks! @Frank@Patronus